# putting condition on a List field using Ebean and Play framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.3, ebean

I have A `Device` class and a `Event` class like this:

```
    @Entity
    public class Device extends Model {

        @Id
        public Long id;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "device")
        public List<Event> events = new ArrayList<Event>();

        ...
    }

    @Entity
    public class Event extends Model {

        @Id
        public Long id;

        @Constraints.Required
        @Formats.DateTime(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm")
        public Date start;

        @Formats.DateTime(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm")
        public Date end;

        @ManyToOne
        public Device device;

        ...

    }
```

I want to get a list (Page actually) of all devices that have NO events between a given `Date from` and `Date to`. well sounds simple but I somehow cannot get what I want using `Ebean`, this is how I think should work, but the devices I'm getting are not right,

```
    Model.Finder<Long, Device> find = new Model.Finder<>(Long.class, Device.class);
    Page<Device> devicePage = find.where()
        .or(
            Expr.lt("events.end", from),
            Expr.gt("events.start", to)
        )
        .orderBy("id asc")
        .findPagingList(10)
        .setFetchAhead(false)
        .getPage(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.or(
    Expr.and(
        Expr.lt("events.start", from),
        Expr.lt("events.end", from)
    ),
    Expr.and(
        Expr.gt("events.start", to),
        Expr.gt("events.end", to)
    )
)
```

The idea is: event's start & end date have to be less than FROM date OR have to be greater than END date.